# play-json - Could not find implicit value for parameter um

Tags: scala, akka-http, play-json

I know this question has been asked many times before, however all of them use spray-json. I wanted to use play-json. This might be why the proposed solutions don't solve the problem.
The trait with the `route` is in a separate file named [RestApi.scala](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/e75ec2289daf7c825745238658ffe7fe). The `Http.bindAndHandle` which makes use of it is in the file named [Main.scala](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/1a99dfe44847f7012b71284a1c0e47ba). Both files without irrelevant element removed are presented below. If you want to see the whole file please click at the links above.

RestApi.scala

```
package restApi

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

trait RestApi {
  import models._
  import cassandraDB.{WriterActor, ReaderActor}
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(20 seconds)

  val cassandraWriterWorker = system.actorOf(Props[WriterActor], "cassandra-writer-actor")
  val cassandraReaderWorker = system.actorOf(Props[ReaderActor], "cassandra-reader-actor")

  val route =
    pathPrefix("api") {
      pathSuffix("contact") {
        // the line below has the error
        (post & entity(as[Contact])) { contact =>
          complete {
            cassandraWriterWorker ! contact
            StatusCodes.OK
          }
        }
      } ~
      pathSuffix("gps"/ "log") {
        // an analogous error message is shown in the line below
        (post & entity(as[GpsLog])) { gpsLog =>
          complete {
            cassandraWriterWorker ! gpsLog
            StatusCodes.OK
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Main.scala

```
package initialization

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import cassandraDB.{ConfigCassandraCluster, ReaderActor, WriterActor}
import gcm.GcmServer
import restApi.RestApi

object Main extends App with ConfigCassandraCluster with RestApi {

  override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  override implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val write = system.actorOf(Props(new WriterActor(cluster)))
  val read = system.actorOf(Props(new ReaderActor(cluster)))
  val gcmServer = system.actorOf(Props(new GcmServer(11054...,"AIzaSyCOnVK...")), "gcm-server")
  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)


}
```

I point out the line where the error occurs in RestApi.scala
Error Message:

```
Error:(31, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[models.Contact]
        (post & entity(as[Contact])) { contact =>
                         ^
```

The `Contact` is a data model defined in [Contact.scala](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/5fad28f12fd54eb36726ca376c9597e7).

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but I really don't think so. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is an easy solution. Simply add `resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("hseeberger", "maven")` to your build file and then `"de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-play-json" % "1.5.3"` to your libraryDependencies and import `import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpplayjson.PlayJsonSupport._` into your code. You can now use play-json like you would use spray-json.